# Question about flushAutomatically in native update query

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

Suppose I have some service with method updateModificationDate:

```
class SomeService { 
...
@Transactional
public MyItem updateModificationDate(MyItem item)  {
   myRepository.updateModificationDate(myItem.getId(), DateTime.now().toDate());
   myItem = find(myItem.getId());//use dao.find
   return MyItem;
}

}
```

updateModificationDate implemented in class MyRepository as following :

```
class MyRepository extends JpaRepository<MyItem, Integer>{ 
    ....
    
    @Modifying(flushAutomatically = true)
    @Query(nativeQuery = true, value = "UPDATE myItemsTable SET modificationDate = ?2 WHERE id = ?1")
    void updateModificationDate(Integer itemId, Date dateToSet);
}
```

The question is: is there need ( and safe ) here to use `flushAutomatically = true` or it is enough without to get item with changed date field?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score -1):

As I only remember that this @Modifying is for use more query other than Select (like when I want to update, delete, or do ddl...)

So I search it again and give you this [baedung link](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-modifying-annotation#clear)

Now the EntityManager is flushed before our query is executed.

You will need to understand about Persistence Context and some more.

But in this case, you only do some update with JPARepo and not EntityManag so We good